# Validate the Date In Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, textbox

How can I determine if the value in my `textbox` is a correct `date`?

**ex:**
this is the value of the date in my Textbox:`01/32/2013`

I know that it is a wrong value of date, but how can I determine that it is a wrong format?
I can avoid that by using **`try and catch`**, but I don't want to use it, I will use it if I don't find a solution in my problem.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMEditStartDt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDt", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'
    CssClass="datePicker" SkinID="textSkin" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditStartDt" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txtMEditStartDt" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" 
    CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" 
    CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
    CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True"/>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="calendarEditStartDt" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtMEditStartDt" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: make you textbox read only so only control and put data in textbox and restrict user from entering data

Comment: @PranayRana the value will become null if I put make my textbox in read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) method. In this method used is a *current* culture of applicaiton. So in case of failure, it will return simply `false`.

```
DateTime dateValue = default(DateTime);
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)) 
   //SUCCESS 
else 
  //FAILURE
```

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you make use of Calander control which put data in your Textbox rather than allowing user to enter date.. this will make sure that user not going to enter wrong data value because  user need to select date from calander control only

or

if you know the data format than you can do like this

```
string dateTimeString = "28/08/2012";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, 
   "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out date))
 {
    //code to process valid date
 }
```

if not valid date than returns false value for it , like this you can validate your data of date

Comment: I am using a textbox that has a calendarExtender and maskedEditExtender
but what if the user type a date and not to choose a date in GUI that is appearing if I click the textbox..

Comment: -1 This won't compile since [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) returns a `bool` which indicates whether it could be parsed to `DateTime` or not. It also requires to pass a `DateTime` variable as `out` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt;

if(DateTime.TryParse("01/32/2013",out dt)){


  //do stuff;
}
```